# msdropdown get selected value

Tags: jquery, msdropdown

I am using msdropdown plugin from [here](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/)

I build dropdown like this

```
var jsonData = [
            {
                text: "Facebook",
                value: 1,
               description: "Description with Facebook",
                image: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
            },
            {
                text: "Twitter",
                value: 2,

                description: "Description with Twitter",
                image: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
            }
            ];
var jsn = $("#byjson").msDropDown({byJson:{data:jsonData, name:'payments'}}).data("dd");
```

I want to get selected value and i tried code like this

```
$("#byjson").change(function () {
        var selectedIndex = $(this).val();
        alert("value =" + selectedIndex);
    });
```

When i select something from dropdown i get value as blank always. I am not able to get selected value. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found it .. Its like this

```
   $("#byjson").change(function () {
        var selectedIndex = $('#byjson option:selected').val();
        alert("value =" + selectedIndex);
    });
```